# Is using Observer design pattern instead of Provider in flutter a good idea?

Tags: flutter, dart, design-patterns, observer-pattern, provider

The thing is that I have an app where I need to manage data across widgets, and listen to modifications (like perform an action in widget "X" whenever the value of a variable in widget "Y" changes).

So I was thinking, instead of using a whole package and adding a library to my dependencies (I mean *provider*) and since dart is an **Object-oriented programming** language... I can use the **observer design pattern** (pub-sub). this way I can listen to variables' modifications and **perform rebuilds only where needed**!

Every interaction is highly appreciated!! THANK U!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `provider` package is only there to make things easier. I think building your own, or using, a pub-sub wouldn't be any easier.

Flutter already provides a [detailed introduction on state management](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt) which you should probably check out first. Start by using the tools provided by the core flutter framework. Then you will find out what benefits `provider`, `riverpod`, `redux`, `rx`, etc. bring to the table and whether they are beneficial to your use cases.